# i tried several techniques but failed to handle this error System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Tags: c#, sql, .net, localdb

I have the following error occured when try to execute my program, do not know how to handle, following is the code , and i also attached the screenshots.
i am new to  .net and sql. Thanks

[image: following is the screenshot of error generate]

```
    public partial class adminInfo : Form
    {
        SqlCommandBuilder scb;
        public adminInfo()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PMS obj = new PMS();
            obj.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            adminAdd_delete obj = new adminAdd_delete();
            obj.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\ddd\Desktop\Pharmacy managment system\Pharmacy managment system\adminInfo.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT        CNIC, [JOB TITLE], SALARY, NAME
FROM            admininfo", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
           dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the error states that you don't have `admininfo` table. Did you check your database for the correct table name?

Comment: You must read `Exception and Error handling` in C# and How to read and understand errors/exceptions message and codes.

Comment: You are trying to read some fields from a TABLE named `admininfo`. Do you have a table with that name in your database  `admininfo.mdf`? Do not confuse the name of the physical file with the name of a table contained in the database

Comment: Always use the "View Detail..." link to get more information

Comment: I think you're using Microsoft SQL localDB. And its usages are little bit different from Oracle MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you're new comer to stackoverflow, I simply suggest to define the DataTable how it looks like,

```
DataTable dt= new DataTable("admininfo");
```

Now, the structure of DataTable is same as admininfo table in SQL database.

You just made a instance of DataTable but you need to set columns manually which belong to the DataTable or automatic way like above.

Hope this helps..

Comment: I apologize my wrong idea but cannot delete accepted answer.